# Free Shipping Products Apply to Order Shipping

Tags: expresso-store

When you have a product that is marked as *free shipping* and a product that has paid for shipping in the same basket, I would imagine that you would still pay for shipping.

A particular client of mine wants it so that if you add any product with *free shipping* you get free shipping for your entire order.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. "Free Shipping" products do not contribute to the total weight used for shipping calculations, but if you have at least one non-free shipping item in your cart, then there will still be a shipping cost.

It's not possible to trigger that rule (one free shipping item makes whole cart free shipping) using the built in methods. You would therefore need to write an extension (or custom shipping method) which checks for any item in the cart, before adjusting the shipping cost to zero.

The extension hook you would need to use is `store_order_shipping_methods`.

https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html#shipping_hooks